# Trying to install NDISWrapper, but get error after "make" command

Tags: networking, drivers

I installed Ubuntu a few days ago, and i am trying to get my internet adapter (the TP-LINK 8200ND, through USB) working, even though drivers don't support linux.

I am trying to install NDISWrapper, as a lot of people reccomended when i searched for solutions. i follow instructions:

"Change directory to that folder, and type in the commands:
make uninstall"

OK, that works fine, i see no errors.

"make"

Here is the output:

```
make -C utils
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raiden/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.60/utils'
gcc -g -Wall -I../driver  -o loadndisdriver loadndisdriver.c
In file included from loadndisdriver.c:37:0:
../driver/loader.h:19:41: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE > KERNEL_VERSION(4,0,0)
                                         ^
Makefile:16: recipe for target 'loadndisdriver' failed
make[1]: *** [loadndisdriver] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/raiden/Desktop/ndiswrapper-1.60/utils'
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'utils' failed
make: *** [utils] Error 2
```

I tried continuing, hoping it's nothing, but the next command (make install as root) gives the same output, and the wrapper doesn't work.

Anyone has an idea how to fix this?

Note: I do not have internet on Ubuntu. I am writing this from Windows where the drivers work fine, so keep that in mind if you wanted to suggest something that needs internet.

Thanks!

Edit: lsusb output:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 2357:0100  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0103 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ActiveJet K-2024 Multimedia Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I have already confirmed that device 2357:0100 is the network adapter, since when i detach it and retry this command, it disappears.

Edit 2: I have managed to get internet through my phone.

Comment: Windows XP .inf and .sys files are needed for ndiswrapper. I doubt that they exist. Second, I suspect that a working native driver exists. Please run and post: `lsusb` with the device inserted. With this information, I will propose a solution.

Comment: check my edit, i added the data

Answer (score 1):

You can use your install-media and install with apt:

```
sudo apt search ndis|grep -i wrap
  graphical frontend for ndiswrapper (installation of Windows WiFi drivers)
ndiswrapper/xenial 1.59-6 amd64
  Userspace utilities for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module
ndiswrapper-dkms/xenial,xenial 1.59-6 all
  Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module (DKMS)
ndiswrapper-source/xenial,xenial 1.59-6 all
  Source for the ndiswrapper Linux kernel module
ndiswrapper-utils-1.9/xenial,xenial 1.59-6 all
  Transitional dummy package upgrading to ndiswrapper
```

Cause of the fact that you need kernel header to compile ndiswrapper I assume that you can install additional packages.

Comment: every time i try to install ndiswrapper from the command (sudo apt-get instal ndiswrapper or any other form of it, like ndiswrapper-source), it says it's already installed, yet i cannot use it

Comment: " yet i cannot use it"  means https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper is not working for you ? what steps exactly don't work ?

Comment: I have followed all instructions, got the windows drivers, but when i try running the commands through the terminal (as i cannot find the graphical interface of ndis), all it says is "sudo: ndiswrapper: command not found"

Comment: This could be another problem with PATH. Please try to search the ndis-packet. it sould be install if you do "dpkg -l|grep -i ndisw" - therefor the first characters should be 'ii'. if so please do a (example !) "dpkg -L  ndiswrapper-utils-1.9" to see where the files are installed. Please call the tool with the full path then like "sudo /usr....ndiswrapper". Please let me know the result.

Comment: the output to "dpkg -L ndiswrapper":
/.
 /usr
 /usr/share
 /usr/share/doc
 /usr/share/doc/ndiswrapper
 /usr/share/doc/ndiswrapper/copyright
 /usr/share/doc/ndiswrapper/changelog.Debian.gz
 /usr/share/man
 /usr/share/man/man8
 /usr/share/man/man8/ndiswrapper.8.gz
 /usr/share/man/man8/loadndisdriver.8.gz
 /usr/sbin
 /usr/sbin/ndiswrapper
 /usr/sbin/ndiswrapper-buginfo
 /sbin
 /sbin/loadndisdriver

Answer (score 1):

Your device is claimed by the driver *rtl8192cu* *AND* the driver *rtl8xxxu* included in all recent Ubuntu versions. I am surprised that it didn't work by default. However, the usual kernel driver is a bit unstable. There is a better and more stable driver available. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtlwifi-new-dkms
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl8xxxu"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the performance has improved.

You confirmed that you have an internal wireless device that you do not wish to use because it evidently doesn't support 802.11N. Let's blacklist its driver:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist rtl818x_pci"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

I also notice this in your paste:

> [   16.197682] rtlwifi: channel plan 0x0
>
> [   16.197684] rtlwifi: bad channel plan 0x0
>
> [   16.197686] rtlwifi: country code 11

I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Reboot with the tether detached and let us hear your result.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44162/discussion-on-answer-by-chili555-trying-to-install-ndiswrapper-but-get-error-af).